# Understanding a part of minimum spanning tree in java code

Tags: java, data-structures, minimum-spanning-tree

Can any one explain this two parts of this code to me which is a part of a java code as an application for data structures for Dijkstra shortest path minimum spanning tree

The first One:-

```
PriorityQueue<Edge> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(allEdges.size(), Comparator.comparingInt(o -> o.weight));
```

The second one:-

```
makeSet(parent);
```

The Code :-

```
 public String MST(){

    PriorityQueue<Edge> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(allEdges.size(), Comparator.comparingInt(o -> o.weight));

    for (int i = 0; i <allEdges.size() ; i++) {
        pq.add(allEdges.get(i));
    }

    int [] parent = new int[vertices];
    makeSet(parent);

    ArrayList<Edge> mst = new ArrayList<>();
    int index = 0;

    while(index<vertices-1){
        Edge edge = pq.remove();
        System.out.println("Source : "+edge.source+", Dest : "+edge.destination+", Weight : "+edge.weight);
        int x_set = find(parent, edge.source);
        int y_set = find(parent, edge.destination);

        if(x_set==y_set){}

        else {
            mst.add(edge);
            index++;
            union(parent,x_set,y_set);
        }
    }
    String str = "";
    str+="Minimum Spanning Tree :-\n";
    str+=printMST(mst);
    return str;
}

public void makeSet(int [] parent){
    for (int i = 0; i <vertices ; i++) {
        parent[i] = i;
    }
}

public int find(int [] parent, int vertex){
    if(parent[vertex]!=vertex)
        return find(parent, parent[vertex]);;
    return vertex;
}

public void union(int [] parent, int x, int y){
    int x_set_parent = find(parent, x);
    int y_set_parent = find(parent, y);
    parent[y_set_parent] = x_set_parent;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What exactly are you struggling to understand? 'Please explain' is a fairly broad request. Are you asking for links to related documentation?

Answer (score 1):

For First Part, It is a property of Priority Queue or Heap, that it can sort 
as per our need and either max or min will always be at top.

Now here, There would be custom class named Edge. It is not there in your code, but it will be there. First part is to sort the priority queue in such a way that edge with minimum weight should come at the top. This is the reason we have used custom comparator.

```
PriorityQueue<Edge> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(allEdges.size(), Comparator.comparingInt(o -> o.weight));
```

As when we find minimum spanning tree, we need edge with minimum weight, so this is done. I have a similar code for Minimum Spanning Tree in Java, let me know if you need it.

Comment: If you can send me the other code that you have please, it might be quite useful to me

Comment: @Omarobaisi. Check out this video on Youtube by William Fiset. [Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jsmMtJpPnhU&list=PLDV1Zeh2NRsDGO4--qE8yH72HFL1Km93P&index=29&t=0s)

Answer (score 1):

This is the PriorityQueue used to get the minimum weight edge

The comparator that declared to the constructor of PQ used to compare two edges based on

weight to heapify the PQ and get the minimum edge, So when you call `Poll()` method will

pick up the minimum edge between vertices